# BufferedReader reads only 61 bytes

Tags: java

i wanna read a 90kb file (which apparently equals approximately 90,000 bytes) using Java's BufferedReader, but it stops after only 61 bytes. The file's alright, I've checked it using an HexEditor.

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> readAsBytes(String dir, String filename, int lineCount) {
    /** Read file as byte*/
    ArrayList<byte[]> outputArr = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    try {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream (dir+filename));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        if (lineCount == -1) {
            String buf = "";
            buf = reader.readLine();
                if (buf != null) {
                    outputArr.add(buf.getBytes());
                }
            }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                String buf = reader.readLine();
                if (buf != null) {
                    outputArr.add(buf.getBytes());
                }
                else continue;
             }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone help? Probably kinda simple mistakes, but it I'm starting to get tired...

Comment: Why are you using a reader if what you want is the bytes? Why not just use a buffered stream.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are passing in a `lineCount` that is `-1` or `1`.

Comment: what linecount value are you passing in?

Comment: There's no part of your code that actually reads the whole file.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use the debugger to see what is happening. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferInputStream` instead `BufferedReader` did the job quite well. Completely forgot that this class exists.